# IDA "Invalid Operand" error when patching

Tags: assembly, x86, patch, disassembly, ida

I am attempting to patch a binary in IDA using the "Assemble" option, and every time I enter an instruction with some arithmetic to calculate the offset, I receive an `Invalid Operand` error. For example:

```
mov [bp-4], bx
```

returns `Invalid Operand`, while

```
mov ax, bx
```

works.

I've attempted playing around with the format of the instruction (eg include `word ptr`, use `4h`, etc) but nothing seems to work. Is there any way about this error, or is entering byte code for patching the only option?

Comment: Try `ebp` there, a pointer must be 32-bit one if you are in 32-bit mode and 64-bit value (`rbp`) if it's long mode.

Comment: I am working in 16-bit mode

Answer (score 7):

according to Hex Rays:

> The assembler command is supported for only a few processors, only a few instructions. We do not plan to extend this feature, sorry

Lame, I know.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but although the Assemble dialog says "Invalid operand" if you know the bytecode you can use the Change byte... menu option instead. You could use OllyDbg to assemble to bytecode (select anywhere and hit space), then copy that into IDA's Change byte dialog as a workaround.